# What's a good program for browsing a folder containing many animated gifs and mp4 short loops?

Tags: media-player, gif, mp4

When everyone just used animated GIFs, I could download a ton of animated GIFs, put them in one folder. I'd open one of the GIFs with Ifranview and then use the arrow keys to go from one GIF to the other for viewing pleasure/browsing.

Now, many websites are using MP4 or other file formats instead of GIFs. And Ifranview can't open mp4s. VLC can open mp4s but I can't move to the next short mp4 loop easily using the arrow keys on the keyboard. And also sometimes, I will have a folder that contains both GIFS and some short mp4 loops.

What's the best software for the best experience?

Also let's say you don't want to have to separate the GIFS and mp4s.